# More than one package matched with specified pattern: %s. Please restrain the search pattern

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I was trying to create a release pipeline in Azure DevOps.
All part works fine but getting error in IIS Web Deploy.

> More than one package matched with specified pattern: %s. Please restrain the search pattern.

[image: Error]

Here is the task for Web Deploy.

[image: IIS Web Deploy]

I have the yml as:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    zipAfterPublish: true
    arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
   pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
   artifactName: AspNetCoreExample
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More than one package matched with specified pattern: %s. Please restrain the search pattern

The zip files are came from your build pipeline. if you need only the `.zip` so configure your build pipeline publish artifacts task to take only this.

However, you have publish your project by the task `VSBuild` and `DotNetCoreCLI:publish`. In this case, you will have one more .zip file in your artifact, which will cause that issue.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2  #Move this task.
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    zipAfterPublish: true
    arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

To resolve this issue, please move the task `- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2` and make sure you have only one package in your `.zip` file.